# How Timer Callback Function Does the Timing?

Tags: timer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know how accurate ROS timer is. So for example, I create the timer as follows:

```
timer1=n.createTimer(ros::Rate(500),&HWController::Timer1_Process,this);
```

There is a callback function here `HWController::Timer1_Process`, which takes an argument of C++ class `ros::TimerEvent`. There are several member variables in this class, one of which is `current_expected_`. I want to know when `current_expected_` is calculated. In ROS [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/roscpp/html/structros_1_1TimerEvent.html), the explanation of this variable is

> In a perfect world, this is when the current callback should be happening.

However, no further information is given. I want this accurate value because I need to calculate the time error as shown below.

```
void HWController::Timer1_Process(const ros::TimerEvent &e)
{
    ros::Duration time_err = e.current_real_ - e.current_expected_;
   .....
}
```

So, to be more specific, is `current_expected_` calculated after this callback function exits (i.e. after the '}' symbol) where it adds the timer period (in this case, 0.0002s) to the current ROS time upon exiting the function? Or is it calculated at the beginning of the function? Actually I prefer to the first explanation because it should not take into account the execution time of this function. I hope someone could clarify this by providing some source codes of its implementation rather than random guessing. I tried to find its implementation but failed. :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260944/how-timer-callback-function-does--the-timing?/) by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2017-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`current_expected` is computed [after the callback](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/lunar-devel/clients/roscpp/include/ros/timer_manager.h#L190) is called. But that is only relevant when the timer [jumps](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/lunar-devel/clients/roscpp/include/ros/timer_manager.h#L413). In normal operation, the value is computed incrementally from the time the timer was [started](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/lunar-devel/clients/roscpp/include/ros/timer_manager.h#L289).

Keep in mind that ros timers and controllers don't go hand in hand. The ros timer's rate varies, and if you dare to set a high rate, the actual rate is going to vary by a lot.

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.ros.org/users/20033/nlamprian/) with karma: 366 on 2017-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2017-05-05**:
[Here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/lunar-devel/clients/roscpp/include/ros/timer_manager.h#L190) is `event.current_expected = current_expected_;`. It only assigns the value of `event.current_expected`  but I cannot find where it computes the value of `current_expected` which confused me.

**Comment by [nlamprian](https://answers.ros.org/users/20033/nlamprian/) on 2017-05-06**:
It's `next_expected` that gets [updated](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/lunar-devel/clients/roscpp/include/ros/timer_manager.h#L409). `current_expected` gets its value from `next_expected` when a TimerQueueCallback instance is created.

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2017-05-06**:
Please fix your last link. So in this way, does it mean that once the timer loop exits, a TimerQueueCallback instance is created, which means the `current_expected` updates once the timer loop exits?

**Comment by [nlamprian](https://answers.ros.org/users/20033/nlamprian/) on 2017-05-06**:
[Here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/lunar-devel/clients/roscpp/include/ros/timer_manager.h#L518) is the last link. A TimerQueueCallback instance is created each time an iteration is scheduled for execution.

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2017-05-06**:
"A TimerQueueCallback instance is created each time an iteration is scheduled for execution." Could you show me how did you come to this conclusion from the source code? Is it because `threadFunc()`, but I could not see where it is called?